# Where could I find the genre of a particular piece?

Tags: discussion

I am interested in identifying the genre of a particular track from a TV show (I have identified the track). I can see that these questions are off-topic here. Where *is* an appropriate venue to ask such questions?

(Alternatively, the question "How do I identify the genre of a track?" seems too huge. Any suggestions?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there are any SE sites which caret  to identifying genre's of song.  You can either make a proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/, or look for a forum somewhere which deals with similar types of music